# How to cover metadata port service test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, metadata-api

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void createKnowledgeFieldsetMetada(){
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = MetadataDeployController.getSessionIdFromVFPageWithEx(Page.DeployApprovalHelper);
        MetadataService.FieldSet fieldSet = new MetadataService.FieldSet();
        fieldSet.fullName = 'Knowledge__kav.myfieldset';
        fieldSet.label = 'myfieldset';
        fieldSet.description ='Field To Display In Verbis Admin';
        MetadataService.FieldSetItem mydisplayedFields = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
        mydisplayedFields.field = 'Summary ';
        mydisplayedFields.isFieldManaged = true;
        mydisplayedFields.isRequired = false;
        fieldSet.displayedFields  = new List<MetadataService.FieldSetItem>();
        fieldSet.displayedFields.add(mydisplayedFields);
        List<verbis.MetadataService.SaveResult> sr = service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { fieldSet });
}
```

I tried with this

```java
private class Test_class implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        String fullJson = 'your Json Response';
        HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        res.setBody(fullJson);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
@IsTest
        
static void service_call() {
    //Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new Test_class());
    //Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new RestServicesMock());
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Test_class());
    Test.startTest();
    AdminController.createKnowledgeFieldsetMetada();
    Test.StopTest();
}
```

with this test method my class is covered but getting a error:

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts in test log;